# Positive lookahead with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been messed up with regex.. I found it difficult for me..I have seen a code like:

```
function myFunction() {
   var str = "Is this all there is";
   var patt1 = /is(?= all)/;
   var result = str.match(patt1);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
```

When i run this code it gave me the output `is`.

But when i add like `/is(?=there)/` it didnt output anything. I am new to regular expression ..hope you guys  can help in in understanding positive lookahead in regex..I have followed many tutorials it didnt helped me.

Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The regex `is(?= all)` matches the letters `is`, but only if they are **immediately** followed by the letters `all`

Likewise, the regex `is(?=there)` matches the letters `is`, but only if they are **immediately** followed by the letters `there`

If you combined the two in `is(?= all)(?=there)`, you are trying to match the letters `is`, but only if they are **immediately** followed both by the letters `all` **AND** the letters `there` at the same time... **which is not possible.**

If you want to match the letters `is`, but only if they are **immediately** followed **either** by the letters `all` **or** the letters `there`, then you can use:

`is(?= all|there)`

If, on the other hand, you want to match the letters `is`, but only if they are **immediately** followed by the letters `all there`, then you can just use:

`is(?= all there)`

**What if I want `is` to be followed by `all` and `there`, but anywhere in the string?**

Then you can use something like `is(?=.* all)(?=.*there)`

**The key to understanding lookahead**

The key to lookarounds is to understand that the lookahead is an assertion that checks that something follows, or precedes **at a specific position in the string**. That is why I bolded **immediately**. The following article should dispel any confusion.

**Reference**

[Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: am sorry still i didnt get "but only if they are followed by the letters all"..how can i know if its folowed or not

Comment: @user3718914 Lookarounds are a bit confusing at the start. I highly recommend you read that article I linked, as it's very clear and will probably do a better job than us trying to write another article here. :)

Comment: @user3718914 Also in the answer I added the bold words **immediately** I think it will help.

Comment: yeah i have accepted the answer ..is this depends on the position of the string too ??..i mean in the case of lookahead

Comment: @user3718914 `is this depends on the position of the string too` Can you please explain what you mean? Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @user3718914 The lookahead says "we can match this" exactly at the position of the lookahead, i.e. after the `is`. If you want it to look ahead further down the string, you include that in the lookahead for instance with a `.*`. So in `is(=.*Bob)`, the lookahead asserts "at this exact position in the string, i.e. after the `is`, I am able to match `.*`, i.e. any characters, then `Bob`. So you are able to look further down the string, but you stay in the same place in the string, after the `is`. Adding the `.*` is like using binoculars.Hey I'm shutting down for the day, hope this is helpful! :)

Answer (score 9):

The **Positive Lookahead** fails for the fact that `there` does not immediately follow **is**.

```
is(?=there) # matches is when immediately followed by there
```

---

To match **is** if `there` follows somewhere in the string, you would do:

```
is(?=.*there)
```

**Explanation**:

```
is          # 'is'
(?=         # look ahead to see if there is:
  .*        #   any character except \n (0 or more times)
  there     #   'there'
)           # end of look-ahead
```

See [**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/qW7tZ1)

A detailed tutorial I recommend: [How to use Lookaheads and Lookbehinds in your Regular Expressions](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-lookaheads-and-lookbehinds-in-your-regular-expressions--net-16203)

Comment: am sorry still i didnt get "but only if they are followed by the letters all"..how can i know if its folowed or not