# Regex exclude last matched character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following input text:

```
Teterboro US [TEB] - 20KM
```

I would like to get the following output :

```
Teterboro US
```

I am using the following expression :

```
.*\[
```

But it I am getting the following result

```
Teterboro US [
```

I would like to get rid of the last space and bracket " ["

I am using JavaScript.

Comment: What did you try and what was the result? Why not just use indexof / substring?

Comment: You want a "positive lookahead", https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226953/positive-lookahead-with-javascript-regex

Comment: Change to `.*(?= \[)`.

Comment: You have multiple options. You can use `[^[]+` without `g` flag, or you can use `.*?(?=\s*\[)` (which I'd suggest)

Comment: `var res = s.split(/\s*\[/)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/.*?(?=\s*\[)/` with `match`; i.e. change `\[` to look ahead `(?=\s*\[)` which asserts the following pattern but won't consume it:

```js
var s = "Teterboro US [TEB] - 20KM";

console.log(
  s.match(/.*?(?=\s*\[)/)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this pattern:

```
.*(?= \[)
```

It is `positive lookahead assertion` and it works just like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (worth mentioning in case you're not familiar with groups) is to catch only the relevant part:

```js
var s = "Teterboro US [TEB] - 20KM";
console.log(
  s.match(/(.*)\[/)[1]
)
```

The regex is:

```
(.*)\[
```

matches anything followed by "[", but it "remembers" the part surrounded by parenthesis. Later you can access the match depending on the tool/language you're using. In JavaScript you simply access index 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use: \w+\s+\w+? Depending upon your input