# Match anything before certain character

Tags: regex

I have the following strings

```
/search?checkin=2018-10-25&checkout=2018-10-27&id=bandung-108001534490276290&page=1&room=1&sort=popularity&type=CITY
/search?checkin=2018-12-09&checkout=2018-12-13&id=singapore-108001534490299035&maxPrice=&minPrice=&room=1&type=REGION
/search?checkin=2018-10-22&checkout=2018-10-23&lat=-6.1176043&long=106.7767146&maxPrice=&minPrice=&room=1&type=COORDINATE
/search?page=1&room=1&type=POI&id=taman-mini-indonesia-indah-110001539700828313&checkin=2018-11-14&checkout=2018-11-16&sort=distance
```

i want to get all string starts from `&id=` until the first `&` so they will return

```
id=bandung-108001534490276290
id=singapore-108001534490299035
id=taman-mini-indonesia-indah-110001539700828313
```

When i tried this regex `\&id=.*\&` it doesn't match my requirement.

Hown do i resolve this?

Comment: i solved the problem by using this regex `\&id=.*?&`

Comment: You might want to use `&id=.*?(&|$)` in case `id` is the last parameter on the line, in which case your regex would fail.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with `[?&](id=[^&]+)`.

- `[?&]` - `?` or `&`, because order of GET parameters is usually not guaranteed and you can get the id in the first place – something like `/search?id=something-123456&checkin=2018-10-25&…`
- `[^&]+` - at least one character that's not `&`
- `()` marks a capturing group

Demo in JS:

```js
const strings = [
  "/search?checkin=2018-10-25&checkout=2018-10-27&id=bandung-108001534490276290&page=1&room=1&sort=popularity&type=CITY",
  "/search?checkin=2018-12-09&checkout=2018-12-13&id=singapore-108001534490299035&maxPrice=&minPrice=&room=1&type=REGION",
  "/search?checkin=2018-10-22&checkout=2018-10-23&lat=-6.1176043&long=106.7767146&maxPrice=&minPrice=&room=1&type=COORDINATE",
  "/search?page=1&room=1&type=POI&id=taman-mini-indonesia-indah-110001539700828313&checkin=2018-11-14&checkout=2018-11-16&sort=distance]"
]

const regex = /[?&](id=[^&]+)/

strings.forEach(string => {
  const match = regex.exec(string)
  if (match) {
    console.log(match[1])
  }
})
```

Demo and explanation at Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/FBeNDN/1/

Answer (score 0):

## [Positive Lookahead `(?=)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24226963/2813224)

Try a positive lookahead:

> ```
> /&id=.+?(?=&)|&id=.+?$/gm
> ```

This part: `(?=&)` means: *if an `&` is found, then everything before it is a match.*
The alternation:`|` (it's an `OR` logic gate) is an update in regards to a comment from Nick concerning that if the parameter ended with an `&id=...`
It's the same match but instead of looking for a `&` it will look for the end of the line `$`. Note that the `m`ulti-line flag is used to make `$` represent EOL.

### Demo

```js
var str = `/search?checkin=2018-10-25&checkout=2018-10-27&id=bandung-108001534490276290&page=1&room=1&sort=popularity&type=CITY
/search?checkin=2018-12-09&checkout=2018-12-13&id=singapore-108001534490299035&maxPrice=&minPrice=&room=1&type=REGION
/search?page=1&room=1&type=POI&id=indo-1999999051158
/search?checkin=2018-10-22&checkout=2018-10-23&lat=-6.1176043&long=106.7767146&maxPrice=&minPrice=&room=1&type=COORDINATE
/search?page=1&room=1&type=POI&id=taman-mini-indonesia-indah-110001539700828313&checkin=2018-11-14&checkout=2018-11-16&sort=distance
/search?page=1&room=1&type=POI&id=indonesia-1100055689`;
var rgx = /&id=.+?(?=&$)|&id=.+?$/gm;
var res = rgx.exec(str);

while (res != null) {
  console.log(res[0]);
  res = rgx.exec(str);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if `id` is the last parameter on the line.

Comment: Indeed, I just saw that, very refined and yes it works, you were just missing the `m` flag in your answer.

Comment: Actually I wasn't planning to answer because the two that are here already more than cover the options. I was just playing with the code snippet that I had copied from your answer and accidentally pressed `Post Answer` instead of `Run code snippet`! :-)